# How to force a link to send data to a servlet and open a url in android?

Tags: android, http, url, servlets, deep-linking

I want to put a link on my website that once clicked will send a request to a servlet with some parameters, and I want the browser to go to www.google.com once the user clicked it.

Is it possible?

Comment: With one click? Or two?

Comment: I want the 2 actions to happen with one click on the link.

Comment: So you are using a browser? Not an app you are programming?